# Create array in bash with variables as array name

Tags: bash, shell-script, array, typeset

I'm not sure if this has been answered, I've looked and haven't found anything that looks like what I'm trying to do.

I have a number of shell scripts that are capable of running against a ksh or bash shell, and they make use of arrays. I created a function named "setArray" that interrogates the running shell and determines what builtin to use to create the array - for ksh, set -A, for bash, typeset -a. However, I'm having some issues with the bash portion.

The function takes two arguments, the name of the array and the value to add. This then becomes ${ARRAY_NAME} and ${VARIABLE_VALUE}. Doing the following:

```
set -A $(eval echo \${ARRAY_NAME}) $(eval echo \${${ARRAY_NAME}[*]}) "${VARIABLE_VALUE}"
```

works perfectly in ksh. However,

```
typeset -a $(eval echo \${ARRAY_NAME})=( $(eval echo \${${ARRAY_NAME}[*]}) "${VARIABLE_VALUE}" )
```

does not. This provides

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token '('
```

I know I can just make it a list of strings (e.g. MYARRAY="one two three") and just loop through it using the IFS, but I don't want to lose the ability to use an array either.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 3):

```
eval "$ARRAY_NAME"'+=("$VARIABLE_VALUE")'
```

(would also work in `zsh` or `ksh93`).

Your `ksh88` one should be:

```
eval 'set -A '"$ARRAY_NAME"' "${'"$ARRAY_NAME"'[@]}" "${VARIABLE_VALUE}"'
```

Answer (score 0):

I find that the following works in bash:

```
eval typeset -a $(eval echo \${ARRAY_NAME})=\( $(eval echo \${${ARRAY_NAME}[*]}) "${VARIABLE_VALUE}" \)
```

The changes I made are (1) prepending `eval` and (2) escaping the parentheses that delimit the array we construct.

However the same command run under ksh after replacing `typeset -a` with `set -A` fails. Would it be possible for you to either:

- Get rid of `typeset` / `set` entirely (I think assigning an array to your variable implicitly sets its type), or
- alter your code so that the two bits of shell-specific code are fully separated?

In both cases, the snippet posted here seems fragile; it may be better to just use the appending operator `+=`, which seems to be available in both bash and ksh.